# Iteration expression i += i

Tags: java

I have just started learning Java and pretty much programming and saw the following for loop expression:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += i)
    System.out.print(i + " ");
```

My understanding is that "i += i" is short for "i = i + i". The output of the loop is "1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64". Cannot get my head around the iteration when "i" is 3 and higher. How can it become 8 etc.?

Comment: `i += i <=> i = i + i <=> i = 2*i`

Comment: `i += i` `!=` `i += 1`

Comment: I wouldn't mind betting the original _really_ just said `i += 1`

Comment: @ZouZou that `<=>` is confusing - I read it as "not equals" !

Comment: @Alnitak Just take it in a mathematical context :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's

> ```
> Iteration 1  => 1+1
> Iteration 2  => 2+2
> Iteration 3  => 4+4
> Iteration 4  => 8+8
> ```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
first increment time : 1 + 1 = 2
second time : 2 + 2 = 4
third time  : 4 + 4 = 8
forth time  : 8 + 8 = 16 ... and so on 32,64,128,256....
```

Hope this helps you to clear your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

With this particular for loop, the print statement is not being executed when i is 3 because i increments from 2 to 4. Let's take a closer look:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += i)

// iteration 1
    System.out.print(i + " ");// prints 1 increment (1 += 1) == 2
------------------------------------------------------------------
// iteration 2
    System.out.print(i + " ");// prints 2 increment (2 += 2) == 4
------------------------------------------------------------------
// iteration 3
    System.out.print(i + " ");// prints 4 increment (4 += 4) == 8
------------------------------------------------------------------
// iteration 4
    System.out.print(i + " ");// prints 8 increment (8 += 8) == 16
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, i becomes 8 because on the third iteration of the loop, i is 4 and increments by itself to become 8.

Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

In expression `x+=y` means really that you are writing `x=x+y`. In your expression `i+=i` really means that you are writing `i = i+i` which is equivalent to `i = 2*i`.

Now how `for` is working...It's calculating `int i = 1` only once. Then it's checking your loop condition `i < 100`. The next step is to calculate next iteration value which will be i = 1 + 1 =2.

The 3rd iteration will calculate value for `i` in such way - `i = 2 + 2 =4`.

The 4rd iteration will be `i = 4 +4 =8`
....

If you want just to add by one, then please change `i +=i` by `++i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += i)
    System.out.print(i + " ");
```

Equivalent to:

```
int i = 1;
while(i<100){
     System.out.print(i + " ");
     i +=i;
}
```

Just to for completeness: `i += K;` is not exactly `i = i + K`; It is i = (TypeOf i ) (i + k)